# How to read a text file that user enters in python

Tags: python

All i have gotten this far is this.

```
f = open(input('enter file'))
lines = f.readlines()
lines[10]
print("lines")
```

any help?
i changed it to lines[0,11]

QUESTION HAS BEEN ANSWERED

Comment: If the question has been answered, please "accept" one of the answers by clicking on the check-mark next to the best answer.

Comment: thanks i didnt know how to do that. but i have done so now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BorrajaX's solution is not ideal because it reads the whole file.  Better is to use python's built in file iterator.  [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) wraps this iterator to count the number of lines returned.

```
f = open(input('enter file'))
for lnum, line in enumerate(f):
  print(line, end='')
  if lnum == 9:
    break
```

**Edit**
Another method (credit to Robᵩ):

```
import itertools
f = open(input('enter file'))
print(''.join(itertools.islice(f, 10)))
```

This is slightly faster, but has higher peak memory.

Comment: Agree, but I didn't want to deviate too much from the original question (but yeah, that's definitely better memory-wise)

Comment: If we are going to stop iterating after 10, try `for line in itertools.islice(f, 10): print(line,end='')` or even `print(''.join(itertools.isclice(f, 10),end='')`.

Comment: Ya was trying to keep it simple.  `sys.stdout.write()` is a little more efficient than the print, too.  I like your oneliner though.

Answer (score 2):

`lines` is a list. `lines[10]` gives you the 11th element of the `lines` list. It doesn't slice it (check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/289011) about slicing notation).

Also, with `print("lines")` you're printing the string `"lines"` , not the **variable** `lines`. Try:

```
f = open(input('enter file'))
lines = f.readlines()
print(lines[0:10])
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to user [Robᵩ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob) to help me realize that I've forgotten my basic Python. **:-D**

You don't need a `min` to control the slicing if you have less than 10 elements:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][0:10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: The bit about `min` is wholly unnecessary. Slicing works correctly, even if there are too few elements in lines.